# Why does my code print different then it returns in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```
Encode_Decode = input("Would you like to Encode, or Decode your text?")


def encode_decode_retry():
    an = input('Sorry, I didn\'t understand. Would you like to Encode, or Decode your text?')
    if an != "Encode" and an != "Decode":
        an = ""
        encode_decode_retry()
    else:
        print(an)
        return an


if Encode_Decode != "Encode" and Encode_Decode != "Decode":
    x = (encode_decode_retry())
    print(x)
```

It prints "Decode", or "Encode", but when I return it, it returns "None". My version is 3.7

Comment: Please, overwrite your question, at least the title. @Heladio is right in his answer but your question title isn’t understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a return statement inside the if clause. Just add return before calling the function

```py
def encode_decode_retry():
    an = input('Sorry, I didn\'t understand. Would you like to Encode, or Decode your text?')
    if an != "Encode" and an != "Decode":
        an = ""
        return encode_decode_retry()
    else:
        print(an)
        return an
```

Comment: Also, there ought to be a better way of doing this. Instead of recursion you could try using a while loop.